UNION returning results only from the first SELECT
I'm trying to fetch results from 2 different tables like these:
 |TEMPERATURETAB|




TIMESTAMP
TEMPERATURE




Time1
ValueT1


Time2
ValueT2



 |HUMIDITYTAB|




TIMESTAMP
HUMIDITY




Time3
ValueH1


Time4
ValueH2



There's no connection between tables,Timestamp are slightly different, so I don't think I should use JOIN
I tried to use UNION (since I don't need Timestamp from Humidity tables I would have deleted when I would have fetched it in php)
SELECT
  Timestamp as 'Time',
  Temperature as 'Temp'
FROM Temperaturetab
WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN '[some timestamp]' AND '[some other timestamp]'
UNION
SELECT
  Timestamp as 'TimeB',
  Humidity as 'Hum'
FROM Humiditytab
WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN '[some timestamp]' AND '[some other timestamp]'

It only returns
Time and Temp

The columns take their names from the first SELECT statement - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html. What is your desired output?

As @user1191247 implied, column names should be the same if you want to get all of the results. If, for some reason, you need to know the origins, and if that's why you have different column names in your query, you could include a third column - Origin, or some such. With that, your query would be SELECT ... as Time, ... as Temp, 'Temperature' as Origin, ...  UNION SELECT ... as Time, ... as Temp, 'Humidity' as Origin ....

Provide the output which you need in for shown source data.

There's only one header line in the results. How do you expect both Time and TimeB to be in that one header?

You should put the Temperature and Humidity in different columns. Use dummy values for the column of the other table.
SELECT
  Timestamp as 'Time',
  Temperature as 'Temp',
  NULL AS 'Hum'
FROM Temperaturetab
WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN '[some timestamp]' AND '[some other timestamp]'
UNION
SELECT
  Timestamp as 'Time',
  NULL AS Temp,
  Humidity as 'Hum'
FROM Humiditytab
WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN '[some timestamp]' AND '[some other timestamp]'

The temperature rows will have NULL in the humidity column, and vice versa.
